# HashMap- java program issues

Tags: java, hashmap

Rather than explaining some big problem, I'll skip all that and list the small loop I am struggling with. Anyways, I have to print the key of a map, so I am using a special way to print the key by switching the value and the key around.

```
for (int i = 0; i < elementData.length; i++){
     System.out.print("[" + i + "]");
     for (Entry<HashEntry<E>, Integer> entry : foob.entrySet()){
         if (entry.getValue().equals(i)){
             System.out.print(entry.getKey().toString());
         }
     }
 }
```

This is my goal: Print [0][1][2][3] like that all the way to 20. Along with that, 9 numbers will go in between those numbers in parens randomly, based on my program.
Here is my result:

```
[0][1]HashSet$HashEntry@7d4991ad[2][3][4]HashSet$HashEntry@4554617cHashSet$HashEntry@28d93b30[5][6][7][8][9]HashSet$HashEntry@232204a1[10][11]
```

So there's just some trick to make it not print all this machine language looking stuff. Anyways, what do I have to do? Looks like 1 thing was supposed to come after [1], 2 things after [4], something after [9], and so on.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So there's just some trick to make it not print all this machine language looking stuff?

Yea.

Don't try to print an instance of a class that doesn't override `Object.toString()`.  That "machine language looking stuff" is simply the output of `Object.toString()`.

However, I *suspect* that your real code is doing this:

```
     if (entry.getValue().equals(i)){
         System.out.print(entry.toString());
     }
```

because `"HashSet$HashEntry@7d4991ad"` looks like the output you would get if you printed a `HashSet.HashEntry` object.  (The other possibility is that you have used `HashSet.HashEntry` objects as keys in your `Map`.)

Comment: It's the second; look at his code: Entry<HashEntry<E>, Integer> entry

Comment: so what do I do to fix this? Is it a simple quick half-a-line-of-code fix? Thanks!

Comment: Instead of printing the `HashEntry` you should extract the key or value component and print that.  However, this is all looking very odd.  Why do you have a `Map` whose entries have `HashEntry` objects as keys?

Comment: I copied it from another piece of code, haha. I thought it seemed strange. Anyways, thanks dude.